# find the location of a clicked point on an image in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to find the coordinates of the point where a user clicks on an image. The click handler will tell me the location of the click with respect to the figure. However, the image is plotted within an axis that is offset from the figure boundary. Is there a way to figure out the position of the axis origin with respect to the figure origin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert from figure coordinates to data coordinates or axes coordinates using [transforms](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#module-matplotlib.transforms). There's a tutorial [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). To convert figure coordinates to data coordinates you can do something like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot((1,2,3,4))

# Point in figure coordinates
ptsFig = (0.5,0.5) 

# Convert figure coordinates to display coordinates
ptsDisp = fig.transFigure.transform(ptsFig)

# Convert display coordinates to data coordinates
inv = ax.transData.inverted()
ptsData = inv.transform(ptsDisp)

# Plot point in data coordinates
ax.plot(ptsData[0], ptsData[1], 'ro', ms = 20)
# Use the figure transform to plot the same point using figure cooridnates. 
ax.plot(ptsFig[0], ptsFig[1], 'g*', ms = 20, transform = fig.transFigure)

plt.show()
```

The red circle plotted with data coordinates is at the same locations as the green star plotted with figure coordinates.

[image: points plotted with different coordinate systems]

If you actually need the location of the axes you can get it with `ax.get_position()`